# Python - cPickle nested datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime, pickle

I have a list of lists, each sublist looking something like this:

```
a = [datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2), 'string', 4.00]
b = [datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 4), 'another_string', 5.00]

list_of_lists = [a,b]
```

To pickle the list:

```
cPickle.dump(list_of_lists, open(filename, 'wb')) #filename defined
```

When run, it raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analyze_data.py", line 129, in <module>
    analyze_data(sys.argv[1]) #because the dump runs inside a function
  File "analyze_data.py", line 77, in analyze_data
    cPickle.dump(list_of_lists, open(filename, 'wb')) 
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

I've replicated the error on Python 2.7.3 and 2.6.8.

Same error/traceback with regular pickle as well. Also, print statements immediately before the cPickle.dump suggest the error occurs here and not somewhere else.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), it sounds like you can cPickle nested objects, not all of which must be built-in types. Perhaps I could change all the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects to strings. No doubt there are many ways to accomplish serializing and I could adjust the code to make the above a non-issue. However, I need to understand why it's not possible, if that indeed is the case.

Can anyone explain why nested datetime objects are not serializable via cPickle/pickle?

EDIT: Pickling the above data structure works fine outside a function. Inside, no dice. See below.

```
def analyze_data(some_id, some_date=default_date): #some_id/some_date (datetime object) defined above
  …
  #create list_of_lists
  …
  string_date = some_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') #works
  filename = '{0}_{1}.p'.format(some_id, string_date) #filename created fine
  cPickle.dump(list_of_lists, open(filename, 'wb')) #kaboom
```

I map this function to other data in other modules, so ideally would like to keep the pickling inside a function call.

Comment: Please post more info - what Python version you are using, for example, because your data structures are picklable for me both under 2.7.3 and 3.3.0.

Comment: +1 to @t.dubrownik. And 2.5.6, and PyPy 1.9.0/2.7.2, both work fine too. And I vaguely remember bug where `from datetime import datetime` could confuse things, which I think that was fixed in 2.3 or 2.4.

Comment: Also, is it actually raising that exception at the `cPickle.dump` call, as opposed to either (a) early, when you define the values, or (b) somewhere completely different, in a `cPickle.load`? Can you print a complete traceback instead of just one line, and ideally (it won't be too slow if you can use a data set this small to repro it) do so using `pickle` instead of `cPickle`?

Comment: what is `repr(list_of_lists)` immediately before `cPickle.dump()`?

Comment: @t.dubrownik - Put python version above, also added edit how the structure pickles fine outside a function.

Comment: @abarnert - put the full traceback, that error with both cPickle and pickle, and that I import datetime and not 'from datetime import datetime'.

Comment: @Stuart: the code for `analyze_data()` that you posted doesn't correspond to the traceback. The former accepts two arguments (some_id, some_date), the latter is called only with one argument (sys.argv).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You're right, it has a `default_date`. Added it. Also, `repr(list_of_lists)` shows nothing. `print list_of_lists` shows the list.

Comment: @Stuart: you could also try to run the same code with pickle instead of cPickle, you might possibly get a better stack trace. In any case, I can't reproduce so far.

Comment: @t.dubrownik: He already tried it with `pickle` when I asked him yesterday, and edited the question, as his comment above shows.

Comment: @Stuart: Please show us the `#create list_of_lists` code. Is it just the three lines at the top, or something else? Also, don't just tell us `print list_of_lists` shows the list, show _us_ the list. The reason J.F.Sebastian asked for it is so we can see if there's anything unexpected or weird.

Comment: @Stuart: http://pastebin.com/BsPKjj2h is a stripped-down complete example of what you say you're doing, and it works fine. (If you suspect `dump` vs. `dumps` is the problem, that works for me too, but feel free to change it.) If you can't strip down your own code to give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), maybe you can add to my code until it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following with `python2.7 test.py`:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# SO 14328382
import cPickle
import datetime

default_date = datetime.datetime.now()

def analyze_data(some_id, some_date=default_date): #some_id/some_date (datetime object) defined above
    #…
    #create list_of_lists
    #…
    a = [datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2), 'string', 4.00]
    b = [datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 4), 'another_string', 5.00]
    list_of_lists = [a,b]

    string_date = some_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') #works
    filename = '{0}_{1}.p'.format(some_id, string_date) #filename created fine
    cPickle.dump(list_of_lists, open(filename, 'wb')) #kaboom

analyze_data('abc', datetime.datetime(2013,3,12))
```

does not throw an error, but generates the file `abc_20130312.p` with contents:

```
(lp1
(lp2
cdatetime
datetime
p3
(S'\x07\xdc\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tRp4
ag3
(S'\x07\xdc\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tRp5
aS'string'
p6
aF4
aa(lp7
g3
(S'\x07\xdc\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tRp8
ag3
(S'\x07\xdc\x03\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tRp9
aS'another_string'
p10
aF5
aa.
```

So start from there by extending it slowly and see where your code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I'd not do anything complicated... I'd write the code you wanted to write. I'd use [dill](http://pythonhosted.org/dill), which can serialize almost anything in python.

```
>>> import dill
>>> import datetime
>>> a = [datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2), 'string', 4.00]
>>> b = [datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 4), 'another_string', 5.00]
>>> 
>>> list_of_lists = [a,b]
>>> 
>>> lol = dill.loads(dill.dumps(list_of_lists))
>>> lol
[[datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 0, 0), 'string', 4.0], [datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 4, 0, 0), 'another_string', 5.0]]
>>>
>>> default_date = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> 
>>> def analyze_data(some_id, some_date=default_date):
...     string_date = some_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
...     filename = '{0}_{1}.p'.format(some_id, string_date)
...     return dill.loads(dill.dumps(list_of_lists))
... 
>>> # no kaboom
>>> analyze_data('123')
[[datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 0, 0), 'string', 4.0], [datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 4, 0, 0), 'another_string', 5.0]]
```

Dill also has [some good tools](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/detect.py) for helping you understand what is causing your pickling to fail when your code fails.